# Hide the text and show only few tags in jquery

Tags: jquery

I have following text in my webpage

JQuery's syntax is designed to make it easier to navigate a document, select DOM elements, create animations, handle events, and develop Ajax applications. jQuery also provides capabilities for developers to [create plug-ins](http://#plugins) on top of the JavaScript library. This enables developers to [create abstractions](http://#create-abstractions) for low-level interaction and animation, advanced effects and high-level, theme-able widgets. The modular approach to the jQuery library allows the creation of powerful **dynamic** web pages and web applications.

The HTML structure is given below

```html
<div id=“mycontainer”>
  JQuery's syntax is designed to make it easier to navigate a document, select DOM elements, create animations, handle events, a. jQuery also provides capabilities for developers to <a href=“http://jquery.com”>create plugins</a> on
  top of the JavaScript library. This enables developers to <a href=“http://www.jquery.com”>create abstractions</a> for low-level interaction and animation, advanced effects and high-level, theme-able widgets. The modular approach to the jQuery library
  allows the creation of powerful <b>dynamic</b> web pages and web applications.
</div>
```

Now I want to hide all the text which is under div id #mycontainer and only show the anchor tags as given below using jquery. I tried with few options using text(), clone() etc.. but could not succeed. Please help me to get the working script

```html
<div id=“mycontainer”>
  <a href=“http://www.jquery.com”>create plugins</a>
  <a href=“http://www.jquery.com”>create abstractions</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this will acheive what you are looking for:-

```js
$(function(){
  $('#mycontainer').html($('#mycontainer').find('a'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="mycontainer">
  JQuery's syntax is designed to make it easier to navigate a document, select DOM elements, create animations, handle events, a. jQuery also provides capabilities for developers to <a href="http://jquery.com">create plugins</a> on
  top of the JavaScript library. This enables developers to <a href="http://www.jquery.com">create abstractions</a> for low-level interaction and animation, advanced effects and high-level, theme-able widgets. The modular approach to the jQuery library
  allows the creation of powerful <b>dynamic</b> web pages and web applications.
</div>
```